# error: installing appscript

Tags: python, macos, installation, sourceforge-appscript

i am having some trouble getting appscript downloaded for python 2.7. when i try to run the easy install im geting a No such file or directory error. Anyone have anyideas on what im doing wrong?

```
$ sudo easy_install appscript
Searching for appscript
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/appscript/
Reading http://appscript.sourceforge.net
Best match: appscript 1.0.0
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/a/appscript/appscript-       1.0.0.tar.gz#md5=6619b637037ea0f391f45870c13ae38a
Processing appscript-1.0.0.tar.gz
Running appscript-1.0.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-eJivX3  /appscript-1.0.0/egg-dist-tmp-BYJoe1
unable to execute llvm-gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'llvm-gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: What version of gcc do you have installed? For example, if you run `gcc -v` on the command line, what is printed?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the needed compiler.

"llvm-gcc-4.2"

Try installing it or specifying it's path if it is already installed.